# I want to make a GUI in Matlab 2021a. I want to upload a file and that will be the input of GUI and graph will generate. How can I do that?

Tags: matlab

i have already the file uploaded in the GUI but it doesn't generate the graph.

```
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile( ...
    {'*.csv;', 'CSV file (*.csv)';
     '*.xlsx',  'Excel Spreadsheet file (*.xlsx)'; ...
     '*.*',  'All Files (*.*)'}, 'Pick a File to Import');
full_filename = fullfile(pathname, filename);
[A, delimiterOut] = importdata(full_filename);
S=fileread(full_filename)
T1=full_filename(:,1);
            T2=full_filename(:,2);
            plot(app.UIAxes,[T1],[T2])
```

what next to do?

Comment: Presumably `importdata` will load the file selected by the user. You haven't written any code to plot anything, so why do you expect a plot to show up?

Comment: I have already added the plot function still its not running.

Comment: You've loaded the contents of the file into variable `A` using `importdata` and into variable `S` using `fileread` but then you haven't done anything with either of those variables. As written, your code actually tries to plot the second character of the filename against the first character of the filename! You need to have a look at what you've read into `A` or `S` (probably you only need one of these two) and get the X and Y data you need by doing the right indexing into that array.

Answer (score 0):

Using MATLAB App Designer to create a simple App to read in a file that contains 2 columns of data and plot them on app.UIAxes can be achieved in the following way.

You were trying to read data for T1/T2 from the filename rather than the data that had actually been imported.

```
classdef app1 < matlab.apps.AppBase

    % Properties that correspond to app components
    properties (Access = public)
        UIFigure  matlab.ui.Figure
        UIAxes    matlab.ui.control.UIAxes
        Button    matlab.ui.control.Button
    end

    % Callbacks that handle component events
    methods (Access = private)

        % Button pushed function: Button
        function ButtonPushed(app, event)
            [filename, pathname] = uigetfile( ...
                                             {'*.csv;', 'CSV file (*.csv)';
                                             '*.xlsx',  'Excel Spreadsheet file (*.xlsx)'; ...
                                              '*.*',  'All Files (*.*)'}, 'Pick a File to Import');
            full_filename = fullfile(pathname, filename);
            [A, delimiterOut] = importdata(full_filename);
            S=fileread(full_filename)
            T1=A(:,1);
            T2=A(:,2);
            plot(app.UIAxes,[T1],[T2])
        end
    end

    % Component initialization
    methods (Access = private)

        % Create UIFigure and components
        function createComponents(app)

            % Create UIFigure and hide until all components are created
            app.UIFigure = uifigure('Visible', 'off');
            app.UIFigure.Position = [100 100 640 480];
            app.UIFigure.Name = 'UI Figure';

            % Create UIAxes
            app.UIAxes = uiaxes(app.UIFigure);
            title(app.UIAxes, 'Title')
            xlabel(app.UIAxes, 'X')
            ylabel(app.UIAxes, 'Y')
            app.UIAxes.Position = [1 273 300 185];

            % Create Button
            app.Button = uibutton(app.UIFigure, 'push');
            app.Button.ButtonPushedFcn = createCallbackFcn(app, @ButtonPushed, true);
            app.Button.Position = [41 203 100 22];

            % Show the figure after all components are created
            app.UIFigure.Visible = 'on';
        end
    end

    % App creation and deletion
    methods (Access = public)

        % Construct app
        function app = app1

            % Create UIFigure and components
            createComponents(app)

            % Register the app with App Designer
            registerApp(app, app.UIFigure)

            if nargout == 0
                clear app
            end
        end

        % Code that executes before app deletion
        function delete(app)

            % Delete UIFigure when app is deleted
            delete(app.UIFigure)
        end
    end
end
```

Note that this was created using MATLAB R2019b rather than R2021a but there shouldn't be any major differences.